# Is there a way in Android to draw a hollow Path on Canvas?

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas, draw, paint

I'm working on an APP in Android and needs to draw things on a Canvas. I want to draw a Path that is hollow, for example something like this image below.

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEkEM.png)

The Path may contains lines, arcs, bezier curves, etc.

Is there a way for me to achieve that?

---

I had tried to draw the Path with a thicker Paint first and draw the Path again with a transparent and thinner Paint. But the problem is: there may be other things drawn on the Canvas. Doing so will cover other things intersecting with the Path.

I had also tried to translate the Canvas and draw the Path twice for the two borders. But it turned out that this will not work, for example a parabola (as shown below, it is not what I expected).

[View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJ65N.png)

Comment: you could try bezier curve https://proandroiddev.com/drawing-bezier-curve-like-in-google-material-rally-e2b38053038c

Answer (score 0):

> I had tried to draw the Path with a thicker Paint first and draw the Path again with a transparent and thinner Paint. But the problem is: there may be other things drawn on the Canvas. Doing so will cover other things intersecting with the Path.

What do you mean? If the first path-line covers other things drawn, it's ok the inner line would also. If the first line does not cover anything the 2nd line won't cover either.

When do you face the issue of having the first line not cover something while the thinner line does?

Comment: What I want is to only draw the borders, thus the inner part of the path will not be covered. What you said is certainly true, if I draw the path this way, the inner part will be covered by both stroke, but I don't want it to happen.

Comment: That is why I need another solution.

Comment: The inner part won't be covered by anything if you draw it after you draw the outer part? I'm still not following

Comment: That certainly will do... But there may be many things already drawn in the inner part. Sometimes, I won't know where to draw this path when I draw the previous ones. So when I want to draw this path, I have to draw all the previous ones again. Plus, I want to draw this path on the top of other things. There may be another line intersecting with the path. It crosses the inner part of the path. But if I draw it after the path is drawn, some part of the path will be covered by this line.